# DJANGO : Can't list the content of a folder located in static directory in my django project

Tags: python, django, glob

In my project I have a folder ***datasets*** in the *static* folder that content 2 others folders. I want to list the content of each of thosefolders and return it in HttpResponse. I define a utility function *list_dir_content* in utils/data.py where I use glob.glob() function by passing it paths of those folders but I recieve an empty result: an empty list [] from the glob.glob() function. How can I fix thet issue regardless of the os (I'm developping my internship project either on ubuntu or windows 10). Thanks! 
Here are the structure of my project and files *views.py*, *models.py*
You can also see the code which call the utility function *list_dir_content*

```
#in views.py    
def server_uts_datasets(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        uts_datasets = Dataset.get_uts_datasets()
        uts_datasets_serializer = DatasetSerializer(uts_datasets, many=True)
        print(uts_datasets)
        return JsonResponse(uts_datasets_serializer.data, safe=False)

#in models.py
@classmethod    
def get_mts_datasets(cls): 
    mts_datasets_files = data.list_dir_content(settings.DATASETS_DIR)
    mts_datasets = []
    for mts_datasets_file in mts_datasets_files:
        dataset_type = 'mts'
        dataset_path = mts_datasets_file
        dataset_name = data.get_dataset_name(mts_datasets_file)
        dataset_nb_instances = data.get_nb_instances(mts_datasets_file)
        mts_dataset = Dataset(dataset_path = dataset_path, dataset_name = dataset_name, dataset_nb_instances = dataset_nb_instances, dataset_type = dataset_type)
        mts_datasets.append(mts_dataset)

    return mts_datasets



#in data.py
   import glob
   import os
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   def list_dir_content(dir_path, file_extension=''):
      files_pattern = dir_path + '/*.' + file_extension
      print("files_pattern : ", files_pattern)
     #files_results_paths = glob.glob(files_pattern)
     files_results_paths = glob.glob('../tsanalysisapp/static/tsanalysisapp/datasets/uts/*.')
     print("files_results_paths : ", files_results_paths)
     return files_results_paths

#in settings.py
MTS_DATASETS_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tsanalysisapp/static/tsanalysisapp/datasets/mts') # paths to datasets in tne server
UTS_DATASETS_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tsanalysisapp/static/tsanalysisapp/datasets/uts') # paths to datasets in tne server
```

Thanks in advance for your kindly help...
[structure of my django project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg1bC.jpg)

Comment: It isn't clear whether your view isn't working or your list_dir_content function.  Does your print line: `print("files_results_paths : ", files_results_paths)` work?

Comment: @FiddleStix, yes it works and prints an empty list: []. The problem is with the glob.glob function which return an empty list.

Comment: I see.  Have you perhaps assumed that you need to give the file path (../tsanalysisapp/...) relative to data.py?  Because you don't, you need to give the path relative to wherever the `runserver` command is being called from.

Comment: @FiddleStix, It doesn't work too when I pass relative path ../tsanalysis/static/tsanalysisapp/datasets/uts/*. to the list-dir_content function in data.py

Comment: I'm suggesting that you replace `glob.glob('../tsanalysisapp/static/tsanalysisapp/datasets/uts/*.')` with something like `glob.glob('.')` or even just `print(os.getcwd())` so that you know what your working directory is.

Comment: We resolve the issue by removing all slashes in the path. So, instead of doing lMTS_DATASETS_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tsanalysisapp/static/tsanalysisapp/datasets/mts'), we did MTS_DATASETS_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tsanalysisapp', 'static', 'tsanalysisapp', 'datasets', 'mts') and it works. Python automatically add the correct directory separator corresponding to the os (here is windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just only replace in the *os.path.join()* function all the slashes */* with *', '* that result in *os.path.join('parent_dir_name', 'subdir_name', ..., 'last_dir_name', '')*:

```
MTS_DATASETS_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tsanalysisapp', 'static', 'tsanalysisapp', 'datasets', 'mts', '*.')
```